# BufReader::lines() over TcpStream stops iteration

Tags: tcp, rust

I have a reasonably simple code using `TcpStream` and `SslStream` around it, reading the socket line by line with `BufReader`. Sometime the iterator just stops returning any data with `Ok(0)`:

```
let mut stream = TcpStream::connect((self.config.host.as_ref(), self.config.port)).unwrap();
if self.config.ssl {
    let context = ssl::SslContext::new(ssl::SslMethod::Tlsv1_2).unwrap();
    let mut stream = ssl::SslStream::connect(&context, stream).unwrap();
    self.stream = Some(ssl::MaybeSslStream::Ssl(stream));
} else {
    self.stream = Some(ssl::MaybeSslStream::Normal(stream));
}

...

let read_stream = clone_stream(&self.stream);

let line_reader = BufReader::new(read_stream);

for line in line_reader.lines() {
    match line {
        Ok(line) => {
            ...
        }
        Err(e) => panic!("line read failed: {}", e),
    }
}
println!("lines out, {:?}", self.stream);
```

The loop just stops randomly, as far as I can see and there's no reason to believe socket was closed server-side. Calling `self.stream.as_mut().unwrap().read_to_end(&mut buf)` after loop ended returns `Ok(0)`.

Any advice on how this is expected to be handled? I don't get any `Err` so I can assume socket is still alive but then I can't read anything from it. What is the current state of the socket and how should I proceed?

PS: I'm providing the implementation of `clone_stream` as the reference, as advied by commenter.

```
fn clone_stream(stream: &Option<ssl::MaybeSslStream<TcpStream>>) -> ssl::MaybeSslStream<TcpStream> {
    if let &Some(ref s) = stream {
        match s {
            &ssl::MaybeSslStream::Ssl(ref s) => ssl::MaybeSslStream::Ssl(s.try_clone().unwrap()),
            &ssl::MaybeSslStream::Normal(ref s) => ssl::MaybeSslStream::Normal(s.try_clone().unwrap()),
        }
    } else {
        panic!();
    }
}
```

Comment: *there's no reason to believe socket was closed server-side* — can you prove this one way or the other? Reading zero bytes on a closed socket is a normal case, and it sounds like what you have.

Comment: Please try to reduce your test case and produce an [MCVE](/help/mcve). As it is, we have no idea what `clone_stream` does. Additionally, this *could* just be a bug in the SSL wrapper, so try removing the conditional and pin it down to one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, this was a "default timeout" on client I guess (socket was moving into `CLOSE_WAIT` state).

I fixed it by first adding:

```
stream.set_read_timeout(Some(Duration::new(60*5, 0)));
stream.set_write_timeout(Some(Duration::new(60*5, 0)));
```

that made the iterator fail with `ErrorKind::WouldBlock` on timeout, at which point I added a code to send a ping packet over the wire, the next iteration worked exactly as expected.